# play and pause the videos in the bxslider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, bxslider

I am working on bxslider jquery plugin. I am including the videos also. If the current slider is video means when i will click the next button, the current video will be pause and when i come again that video slider that video will be auto play where the video was paused.I need to handle all the video like this. I use video tag for video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/uaznwrh2/1/).

Here is the [API document](http://bxslider.com/options) of bxslider.

> ```
> onSlideBefore
> ```
>
> Executes immediately before each slide transition.

So we pause all the video when this event triggered.

```
$bxslider.find('video').each(function() {
  this.pause();
});
```

> ```
> onSlideAfter
> ```
>
> Executes immediately after each slide transition. Function argument is the current slide element (when transition completes).

So we play the video which is in current active slide.

```
// arguments:
// $slideElement: jQuery element of the destination element

// get the video element, assume only one video in each slide
var video = $slideElement.find('video')[0];
// if this slide contains video and video has been played then continue the video
video !== undefined && video.currentTime !== 0 && video.play();
```

Comment: can you tell me how the "touchEnabled","swipeThreshold","oneToOneTouch","preventDefaultSwipeX","preventDefaultSwipeY" is working.
my code is http://jsfiddle.net/2Fcxw/117/

Comment: @kalles You need test those options on a touch device or a simulator. And the [document](http://bxslider.com/options) explains those options.